# How to set value on click of link in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, dom-events, vaadin7, vaadin-touchkit

I am new to vaadin. I have one Link like

> Link link = new Link("", new ExternalResource(redirectURL));

my requirement is, I have to set value when user clicks the link. Can I add listener when user click the link. Or is there alternate ways of setting value if link is clicked.

Comment: What value do you have to set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To capture onClick on a link or a label, I always create a `HorizontalLayout` and put the component inside it:

```
HorizontalLayout hor = new HorizontalLayout();
final Link link = new Link("Click on Me!", new ExternalResource("http://www.google.com"));
hor.addComponent(link);
hor.addLayoutClickListener(new LayoutClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {
        // capture the click here and do whatever you'd like to do, e.g.
        // if ( event.getClickedComponent() != null ) {
        // if(event.getClickedComponent().equals(link)) {}
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me not :-(. Adding the listener to layout causes link failure.

Answer (score 3):

I interpreted your question as changing the caption of the link. As far as I know it's not possibly with the Link component. Take a look at the activelink addon: http://vaadin.com/addon/activelink.

This addon behaves like Link and lets you add a `LinkActivatedListener` to it. The code should look like this:

```
final ActiveLink link = new ActiveLink("", new ExternalResource(redirectURL));
link.addListener(new LinkActivatedListener() {

    @Override
    public void linkActivated(LinkActivatedEvent event) {
        link.setCaption("newCaption");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new [BrowserWindowOpener](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/BrowserWindowOpener.html) class:

From the API:

> Component extension that opens a browser popup window when the
>   extended component is clicked.

Example:

```
BrowserWindowOpener browserWindowOpener = new BrowserWindowOpener(new ExternalResource("http://google.com"));
/*
 * Apparently, the BrowserWindowOpener method setWindowName uses the HTML5 target
 * attribute (no longer deprecated as it was in HTML4).
 * So you can use either a frame name, or one of four special attribute values:
 * _blank, _self, _parent, _top
 * 
 * browserWindowOpener.setWindowName();
 */
final Button btn = new Button("Click me");
browserWindowOpener.extend(btn);

btn.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        btn.setCaption("clicked");
    }
});
```

More information [here](https://vaadin.com/old-forum/-/message_boards/view_message/2466846).

Answer (score 0):

I dint work on Vaadin yet But I looked into the document. I found that the `Link` class internally extends `AbstractComponent` class which has many functions which you can override. like it has `addListener` function where you need to pass the `Component` listener as a parameter and can detect the click event and do whatever you want to.

For reference check [**this**](https://vaadin.com/api/7.1.11/com/vaadin/ui/Link.html)

and [**this too**](https://vaadin.com/api/7.1.11/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html)

Hope this will help :)