# Click Event in vaadin

Tags: events, vaadin, actionlistener, mouseclick-event

Is it possible to add click event to a option group. on click of option group i have to do some operations & i know about value change listeners but it won't be enough for my events

any suggestions are accepted gladly

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use layout click listener

Comment: can u show me one example

Comment: because i tried many ways no one helped me out

Comment: well gimme some time , i have to look for sample, probably i dont have the same as you are looking for but may be sort of reference code

Comment: A Layout click listener might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679744/how-to-set-value-on-click-of-link-in-vaadin/22817208?noredirect=1#comment54276347_22817208